# AS3 Embedded font won't show up

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

Using FlashDevelop with the Flex SDK, I'm trying to embed a font in the swf file, using the following code:

```
[Embed(source = '/asset/Frutiger-Normal.ttf', fontName = 'Frutiger')]
public static var Frutiger:Class;

(...)

var textField:TextField = new TextField();
textField.embedFonts = true;
textField.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Frutiger', 12, 0x000000);
textField.text = "Hello World!";
stage.addChild(textField);
```

But for some reason, the text won't show up in the embedded font. When 'embedFonts' is set to false, the text will be visible, but in the default font.

The font itself should load, when I change the path to the font to an incorrect one, the compiler throws an exception, so it should be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the font.

```
[Embed(source = '/asset/Frutiger-Normal.ttf', fontName = 'Frutiger')]
public static var Frutiger:Class;
Font.registerFont(Frutiger);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried this, but it still won't show up. Any suggestions?